# Get first item in firestore collection query that does not match given id

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of questions and users collection that has a list of question IDs the user has already answered.

```
/questions/{questionID}

/users/questionsAnswered[questionIDs]
```

What I want to do is query the questions collection and randomly get the first question whose ID does not exists in the users questionsAnswered List.

```
db.collection('questions').where(docID, "not-in", [questionsAnswer])
```

Is there a way to specify the **docIDs** of the questions collection in the where clause?

Comment: You will have to get the questions they've answered and use it in your not-in condition. Have you tried that?

Comment: @windowsill the `[questionsAnswered]` in the where clause is a list of `docIDs` the user has already answered, is that what you are referring to?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for `where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "not-in", whatever)`

Comment: Sounds like an answer @windowsill! :-D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to User @windowsill this is easily possibly with the following example

```
db.collection('collection')
.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "not-in", array)
```

This doesn't get a random one, but there is another Stackoverflow question that shows how to get a random doc from a collection. So you could just combine the two solutions.